# HWIOAuthBundle listener complete work

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

i have problem with HWIOAuthBundle and google authentication, i can't complete work on OAuthProvider. After flush data, i want return entity object, that i saw example somewhere in stackoverflow. 
But when i return $obj; 
I catch error :

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\OAuthToken::__construct() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /var/www/integra/vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/OAuthProvider.php on line 109 and defined

Construct this class :

```
public function __construct($accessToken, array $roles = array())
{
    parent::__construct($roles);

    $this->setRawToken($accessToken);

    parent::setAuthenticated(count($roles) > 0);
}
```

Then i return:

```
  return new JsonResponse(['accessToken' => $user->getToken(), 'Roles' => $user->getRoles()]);  // I catch error what it loadUserByOAuthUserResponse() must return a UserInterface
```

class OAuthProvider extends OAuthUserProvider
    {

```
    protected $container, $em;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->em = $em;
    }


public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
{
    $email = $response->getEmail();

    if ($email === null) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("User email adress not found", 404);
    }

    $name = $response->getFirstName();
    $surname = $response->getLastName();
    $photo = $response->getProfilePicture();



    $repository = $this->em->getRepository('IdamasBillingBundle:User');
    $user = $repository->searchByNameSurnameEmail($email);

    if($user){

        $login = new User();
        $login->setEmail($email);

        $session = $this->container->get('session');
        $session->set('login', $login);

        return $user;

    } else {

        $user = new User();
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setName($name);
        $user->setSurname($surname);
        $user->setPosition('Just user');
        $user->setRoles(1);
        $user->setPhoto($photo);

        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();

        $session = $this->container->get('session');
        $session->set('login', $user); 

//        return $user;f
        return new JsonResponse(['accessToken' => $user->getToken(), 'Roles' => $user->getRoles()]);  
    }

    //return new RedirectResponse("/billing");
}

}
```

How i can to do it, that redirect to complete login page?

Comment: `$user->setRoles([]);`

Comment: public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

Comment: And you set roles to `1`, this is integer! Roles should be a array in your `User` object, `getRoles` must return array, to add role use `addRole()` method, also why you create new user if user exist?

Comment: create user if his not exists

Comment: Really? `if($user){ $login = new User();`

Comment: yes you are right, my mistake...

Comment: public function setRoles($roles)
    {
       $this->roles[] = $roles;
       
       return $this;
    }

Comment: but when i catch error with insert that array to string conversation

Comment: or addRole must be with roles entity?

Comment: can show example because i confused

Answer (score 0):

`User` object should have `roles` property, and it must be an array:

```
class User {

    protected $roles = [];

    public function getRoles() {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function addRole($role) {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
    }

}
```

Comment: how i can save array roles? Maybe need ORM options for array?

Comment: why it should be array?

Comment: So you don't know how to save array in db, you don't know why it should be array, so you just want one role per user, really you don't need roles on user. So I have no idea why you set `1` when you create new user. Good Night.